# Metodo con un parámetro String, no acepta variables tipo String, pero si acepta una cadena puesta manualmente

Tags: java, string

Saludos, tengo un método que recibe como parámetro una variable tipo String, esta misma antes de ejecutar el método le asigno valor con substring, y al invocar el método con dicha variable manda errores. Sin embargo al introducir valores manualmente lo ejecuta sin problemas.

```
String link_to_qr = usuario.substring(usuario.indexOf("www"), usuario.length() - 3);
String path_qr_code= qr.getQr(link_to_qr);
```

Metodo:

```
public String getQr(String link){
/*genera codigo qr*/
}
```

¿Hay algún factor que haga que mi método no funcione? Revise el tipo de dato que genera substring y es String.

Comment: Como llamas al metodo EJ: `generarQr();`

Comment: `String variable = otra_variable.subString(x,y);
String path = generarQr(variable);`

Comment: Pon en la pregunta el error que te manda.

Comment: No es un problema de ese método es que el programa no encuentra el archivo que tratas de obtener.

Comment: Si es un problema del metodo, cuando asigno valores tipo "cadena" por ejemplo, ejecuta el metodo y crea mi archivo.

Comment: No encuentra el archivo `personax.png` el metodo funciona bien, al momento del obtener el archivo no funciona.

Comment: De ser asi no funcionaria si ingreso valores manualmente a mi metodo, y se ejecuta y tambien crea el archivo que quiero con dicha cadena.

Comment: Pon tu código completo porque el método no es el queda el error.

Comment: Cuál es el error que te sale?, Seguro que la variable `usuario` llega con el valor correcto?

Comment: Podrías dar un ejemplo de un valor que pasas al método y que resultado esperas?

Answer (score 1):

Si tu método trabaja bien con valores que pasas sin procesarlo, pero falla con valores procesados por el `substring`, la lógica manda que cometiste un error en los indices de tu substring y luego no recibes el resultado que esperas. Como no puedo adivinar que valores procesos y que resultados esperas, hacemos una IOC (inversion of control) y te presento un ejemplo que tu código hace, para que puedes compararlo con que **quieres** hacer:

si paso la cadena `"http://www.foobar.org/foo.bar"`a tu método, recibo `"www.foobar.org/foo."`. Me imagino que eso no es lo que quieres, ¿o sí?.

Explicandote tu código:

- `substring(int from, int to)` te da la parte del String desde el caracter en posición `from`(incluido) hasta pero excluyendo el caracter en posición `to`.
- `indexOf(String substr)` te da la posición de la primera aparencia de `substr` en tu cadena o -1, si no contiene `substr`

Entonces tu código te da la parte incluyendo el `www` hasta el fin de tu cadena menos 3 caracteres.

Answer (score 0):

buen día, no sé como invocas tu método que recibe el String, pero mira te muestro algo  similar a como describes tu problema, asignar valor a un String mediante subString antes de llamar a método:

```
public class InvoqueString {

    public static void main(String args []){
        String cadena="Stack Over Flow";
        String valor1 ="";
        valor1 = cadena.substring(2, 6);
        recibirString(valor1);

    }

    public static void recibirString(String value){

        System.out.println("Valor recibido: " + value);

    }

}
```

Comment: Hago exactamente eso, y empieza a arrojar errores, con una variable, pero si ingreso al método una cadena tipo "cadena", manualmente con las comillas, funciona.

Comment: Podrías mostrar tu implementación y el error que te arroja para poder ayudarte mejor, ya que el código que te muestro funciona correcto.

Comment: `String link_to_qr = usuario.substring(usuario.indexOf("www"), usuario.length() - 3);
   String path_qr_code= qr.getQr(link_to_qr); `

Comment: Adecue el código que muestras pero recibe y retorna un String correcto, vuendo la traza de tu error, el problema está en otra sección de tu proyecto en la cual trata de obtener un icono .png.